# Sonarqube wrongly shows 'Possible null pointer dereference' error

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have following code, and sonarqube complains of possible null pointer dereferencing at line 5

```
ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata(); //1
metaData.setContentType("image/jpeg"); //2
if(null != result && null != result.getBody()){ //3
      final byte[] body = result.getBody(); //4
      metaData.setContentLength(body.length); //5
      ....
}
```

'result' is an instance of ResponseEntity representing result fetched from a remote service.

I have null checks in place, and I can't understand why soanrqube reports this error?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `result.getBody()` gives the same result each time it is called. At least sonarqube does not know about it.

Comment: To expand on @Henry's comment - call it once, assign it to a variable.  If you want to do it in a shorthand fashion, use the ternary operator: final byte[] body = result == null ? null : result.getBody();  You can then use the result of this expression as the only condition in your if-statement on line 3.